# Reporting Services, Parameters Conditional Formatting

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Could someone please help me with the below.

Is there a way that I can tell reporting services to group unique drop down?

E.g.

```
  ID  |  Type
--------------
 1111 | sick.1
 2222 | sick.2
```

Selecting query from the database, the drop down will have both. I have figured a way to make `type=sick` but the display still shows `sick sick` (so duplication). Its just for the user selection really.

Comment: Are you going to use the ID or the Type as the value of your parameter? Does the type actually have the values `sick.1` and `sick.2`, or did you include the `.1` and `.2` to indicate that these were separate records?

Comment: Hi Mark. The type .1 and .2 does have values associated with it and in my report, I have 2 separate fields for them. I would like to make the parameter unique butthen the report display the values for both.

Comment: Your comment says that you have two separate fields for them, but your question shows them as values in the same field (column) for different rows. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

To select distinct types only, try:

```
select distinct Type from myTable
```

To select distinct types with the smallest associated ID, try:

```
select min(ID), Type from myTable group by Type
```

EDIT: To display everything before the first `.`, replace `Type` with `left(Type, charindex('.',Type)-1)` .